# How can I perform client-side video download with python youtube-dl and meteorjs

Tags: video, meteor, youtube, meteor-blaze, youtube-dl

In my meteor app, i use youtube-dl to download video from youtube and others websites; 
actually, i can get information about the video from server side using code below

```
 var exec = Meteor.npmRequire('child_process').exec;
  var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");

Meteor.methods({
    'comman': function(url){
      this.unblock();
      var future = new Future();

      exec("youtube-dl -F " + url, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

        future.return({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});
      }); 

      return future.wait();
    }
});
```

And the call on the client

```
Meteor.call('comman', url, function(error, result){
        if (result.stdout) {
          console.log('output:' + result.stdout);

       } else {
          console.log('error:'+ result.stderr);
       }
      });
```

The next step is that the user can see thumbnail of the video, the list of formats available, be able to download and save the format he wants from the client side;

How can I perform that??
Any ideas?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this package https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm to your Meteor app to be able to use Npm packages.

Then use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core instead of exec command with youtube-dl, it's easier. In order to use it, you have to add to packages.json in your main folder:

```
{
  "ytdl-core":"0.7.9",
}
```

Now on server.js create a method using a ydtl-core example. You need to use Futures to wait for a response and return it back to client:

```
// load future from fibers
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");

// load ytdl-core
var ytdl = Meteor.npmRequire('ytdl-core');

Meteor.methods({
  // Get info from Youtube video
  'getVideoInfo':function(videoUrl) {
    this.unblock();
    var future = new Future();

    ytdl.getInfo(videoUrl, function(err, result) {
      future.return(result)
    });
    return future.wait();
  },
});
```

On client.js:

```
var videoUrl = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=I8qtzxpDM4k";

Meteor.call('getVideoInfo', videoUrl, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  console.log (result.thumbnail_url);
}
```

EDIT: To download video you can create a link and click it using javascript. You have to pick format which you want to download. In this example I'm downloading first available format.

on client.js

```
var videoUrl = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=I8qtzxpDM4k";

Meteor.call('getVideoInfo', videoUrl, function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  console.log (result.thumbnail_url);
  downloadLink(result.formats[0].url);
}

downloadLink = function(link) {
  //Create url to download from
  var url = document.createElement('a');
  // Add direct video link to a clickable link
  url.setAttribute('href', link);
  // Add download attribute to initiate download
  url.setAttribute('download', 'filename.mp4');
  // Click to start download
  url.click();
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer; exactly what I'm looking for. What about downloading from the client ?? how can I do it after getting url ?

Comment: in downloadLink(result.formats[0].url);
if I connect each format with a link(<a href={{url}}>); how can I get the url of clicked link ??, I try to do it with click function on a, and alert $(this).url, but it throw always  the same url for all format. I'am missing something?

Comment: because you're returning formats[0] - that means first link in the format's array. You might wanna look at basic javascript before you start with Meteor

Comment: I don't include (result.formats[0].url)  in my code; but i include $(this).url in my function and return the same url whatever the format I click; that why I ask you the question